How to hide user jwt from browser inspect on Api request header
As a frontend developer, I have to send the token inside request header.
When I make api calls from web app frontend (lets assume REST Api), anyone can see it from browser inspect including the Api request headers having Authorization as well. Screenshot attached

Which is obviously very simple for anyone to gain access to our server. I want to know how do website developers tackle this when you have to send the token inside request header and not in cookies?
As a frontend developer if I have to send the token inside request header and not in cookies.
